# Kendo Grid column resize end event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, kendo-grid

Does anyone know if there is an event fired on Kendo Grids once you have stopped re-sizing the columns?

I can't find anything on the documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid[1](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid)

If there isn't one, can anyone suggest how I might bind a column resize end event to the grid?

Comment: Isn't `columnResize` the event you want?

Comment: [columnResize](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-columnResize)

Comment: Thanks I will investigate that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **columnResize** function fires once you have stopped re-sizing columns.

You can either set this in your grid configuration during initialisation like this:

```
resizable: true,
  columnResize: function(e) {
    console.log(e.column.field, e.newWidth, e.oldWidth);
  }
```

Or, bind to the event after the grid has been initialised:

```
function grid_columnResize(e) {
  console.log(e.column.field, e.newWidth, e.oldWidth);
}

var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("columnResize", grid_columnResize);
```

The official Kendo documentation can be found here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-columnResize

Hope that helps